# VSTS State Graph Queries

Tags: azure-devops

**Example:** I created a bug workitem, its inital state is `New`, the user `dev1` (assign the ticket to herself) takes the work item and fixes the bug (state is `Fixed`). Now a tester `tester1` takes the workitem (state = `Test in progress`) and does NOT assign it to herself (assignee is still `dev1`). `tester1` now changes the ticket state to `Test done`.

**What I need:** A query that returns all workitems `tester1` was working on.

**What I tried** (but didn't work):

```
    | State   | Was Ever       | Test in progress |
And | History | Contains Words | tester1          |
```

```
    | State      | Was Ever       | Test in progress |
And | Changed By | =              | tester1          |
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot history query to get this result. According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#fields-that-support-history-auditing-and-revision-tracking): History field queries return work items whose Discussion comments or Description fields contain words that match the keywords entered. You can't use the History field to query on changes made to other fields.

We can use the field Changed By to query it, please check the pic. The work item Test_Agile is the sample work item.

**Note**: This field queries only the last change user.

[image]
In addition, we can get the [work item history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to check the work item. Here is an [sample code](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx) to check the all history. We should change the TFS API to Azure DevOps API.